# Windows Lost Partition Recovery [Emergency]

Tags: windows, data-recovery, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

I accidentally deleted my E drive partition and i did not know. I extended my C drive, hence E drive's unallocated space was extended in the C drive. Now how can i get my files back of E drive?

Its kind of emergency, can someone help me?
[An Image Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrEOE.png)

Comment: You can't. The possibility of recovering deleted files/folders/partitions depend on the data not being overwritten and that happen already. On top of that, even if you could recover something, the recovery partition as it was couldn't be recovered so it's useless. Recovery partition are there for a very specific purpose. Backups are necessary either way,

Comment: No way then because I used the unallocated partition alrdy in the C drive?!

Comment: Yes, sort of. The problem is when you extended the partition into the space formerly used by the recovery partition Windows might have written system files there and just a few megas of truncated data is enough to render any eventual file recovered from there using the available tool useless for the purpose a recovery partition has. That's it, unfortunately.

Comment: I should not have extended, this happend only because i didnt even know that i deleted my partition, all is due to some shit youtube videos without pre-cautions.

Comment: I gotta be sue now by my parents, uh god....

Comment: I know the feeling... But that would be an overreaction. The recovery partition is there only to allow resetting Windows easily. The same can be done as well booting from the Windows installation media. There are no user files in recovery partitions so nothing important was really lost. Recovery partitions aren't mandatory for Windows.

Comment: You are down to file scavenging whatever wasn't overwritten. Names & directories are gone, some files *may* have survived. TestDisk or PhotoRec would be prime apps. Stop using the disk immediately, boot from another drive/USB & use another physical drive to recover to. Every write your OS does reduces the chances of recovery. *This is why we have backups.*

Comment: If the files are very valuable to you, and you are willing to pay a fair amount, there are forensic recovery services. STOP USING THE DISK IMMEDIATELY if you plan to retrieve anything. Note that even these costly services may not be able to recover much.